# IMAP search email from particular domain

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

What would be the IMAP command to search for email sent from a particular domain? Like I want to get all email that was sent from yahoo.com. How can I search for that? I am trying to do this with gmail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't tried very hard. The key question is: What do yahoo.com questions have in common? Once you know that, you can construct a search command such as

```
a uid search from "@yahoo.com>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try it out. I started trying out IMAP an hour ago, all the examples I found on the web, none of them hinted that even part of the from string should work (it does not work in Gmail search though). I will try it through IMAP.